# CSV file appearing backwards and RSpec failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to Ruby in general and cannot find a solution as to why my `entries_2.csv` is imported backwards.  My other `.csv` import appears to be the same syntax and is working fine.

Here is the portion of my RSpec for .csv method:

```
require_relative "../models/address_book"

RSpec.describe AddressBook do

let(:book) {AddressBook.new}

def check_entry(entry, expected_name, expected_phone_number, expected_email)
    expect(entry.name).to eq(expected_name)
    expect(entry.phone_number).to eq(expected_phone_number)
    expect(entry.email).to eq(expected_email)
end

describe "#import from csv" do

    it "imports the correct number of entries" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
        book_size = book.entries.size

        expect(book_size).to eq 5

    end

    it "imports the 1rst entry" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
        entry_one = book.entries[0]
        check_entry(entry_one, "Bill", "555-555-4854", "bill@blocmail.com")

    end

    it "imports the 2nd entry" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
        entry_two = book.entries[1]
        check_entry(entry_two, "Bob", "555-555-5415", "bob@blocmail.com")

    end

    it "imports the 3rd entry" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
        entry_three = book.entries[2]
        check_entry(entry_three, "Joe", "555-555-3660", "joe@blocmail.com")


    end

    it "imports the 4th entry" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
        entry_four = book.entries[3]
        check_entry(entry_four, "Sally", "555-555-4646", "sally@blocmail.com")

    end

    it "imports the 5th entry" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
        entry_five = book.entries[4]
        check_entry(entry_five, "Sussie", "555-555-2036", "sussie@blocmail.com")

    end

    it "imports an additional 3 entries" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries_2.csv")
        book_size = book.entries.size

        expect(book_size).to eq 3

    end

    it "imports 1rst entry into additional csv" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries_2.csv")
        entry_one = book.entries[0]
        check_entry(entry_one, "Ralph", "222-222-2222", "ralph@comcast.net")

    end

    it "imports 2nd entry into additional csv" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries_2.csv")
        entry_two = book.entries[1]
        check_entry(entry_two, "Will", "333-333-3333","Will@comcast.net")

    end

    it "imports 3rd entry into additional csv" do

        book.import_from_csv("entries_2.csv")
        entry_three = book.entries[2]
        check_entry(entry_three, "Foobarr", "444-444-4444", "Foobarr@comcast.net")

    end
end
```

Here is my two .csv files:

`entries.csv`

```
name,phone_number,email
Bill,555-555-4854,bill@blocmail.com
Bob,555-555-5415,bob@blocmail.com
Joe,555-555-3660,joe@blocmail.com
Sally,555-555-4646,sally@blocmail.com
Sussie,555-555-2036,sussie@blocmail.com
```

`entries_2.csv`

```
name,phone_number,email
Ralph,222-222-2222,ralph@comcast.net
Will,333-333-3333,Will@comcast.net
Foobarr,444-444-4444,Foobarr@comcast.net
```

Here is the error I am receiving when checking my RSpec:

Failures:

1) AddressBook#import from csv imports 1rst entry into additional csv
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eq(expected_name)

```
   expected: "Ralph"
        got: "Foobarr"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:8:in `check_entry'
 # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:142:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) AddressBook#import from csv imports 2nd entry into additional csv
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eq(expected_name)

```
   expected: "Will"
        got: "Ralph"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:8:in `check_entry'
 # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:150:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

3) AddressBook#import from csv imports 3rd entry into additional csv
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eq(expected_name)

```
   expected: "Foobarr"
        got: "Will"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:8:in `check_entry'
 # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:158:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 0.05492 seconds (files took 0.2885 seconds to load)
17 examples, 3 failures

**Why is my `entries.csv` RSpec correct, but my `entries_2.csv` is not?  What am I missing.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming AddressBook is an ActiveRecord model with `has_many :entries` defined on it, the core issue you're running into is that relations are *not* guaranteed to be returned in any specific order, unless you explicitly request it. So this:

`book.entries[0]`

Is actually running:

`SELECT * FROM entries WHERE address_book_id = ?`

And then fetching the first element of that array. Since the above query is not ordered, the order you get back is arbitrary (as you're seeing; *sometimes* it reflects creation order, and sometimes it does not).

What you actually want is something which actually requests the records ordered in the sequence they were created in, like:

`book.entries.order('entries.id ASC')[0]`

Which you can also accomplish by adding `order: 'id ASC'` as a parameter to your `has_many :entries` definition.

Comment: I apologize, but all this is relatively new to me.  `book.entries[0]` through `books.entries[5]` work fine and in the correct order via `"entries.csv"`.  All I really did, at least my thought process, was created a new object of `book` and imported a different file `entries_2.csv`.  The syntax should theoretically be the same as importing `"entries.csv"`, correct?

Comment: Your data is likely importing just fine, and in the order you expect. My hypothesis is that the issue is your *retrieval* of the data does not specify order (see [this thread](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)). To verify that, I'd suggest pausing the test (using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or another debugger) right after you insert your rows, then inspect the test database directly (`bin/rails dbconsole test`, run a query like `SELECT * FROM entries`).

Comment: I'm knowledgeable about that codebase Dustin is talking about, and it's actually *not* a Rails project (wrong SO tags), so all those otherwise valid insight do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution to my problem.  `CSV.parse` sorts `.csv` files alphabetically, I did not know this.  At this point I am unsure how I could manipulate that particular method, however, rearranging my `names` in my `.csv` file solved my problem.

Comment: Hmm.. CSV.parse does not sort rows alphabetically (see http://pastebin.com/bm7E8uVF for a quick proof; though I suppose it depends on what version/implementation of Ruby you're in). Something else is going wrong in your application. I think it would help if you could post the code behind `AddressBook#import_from_csv`.